# How can i pass a dictionary between View Controllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to pass this dictionary to another view controller

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToThird" {
        let Ps = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
        Ps.hourDictionary = Time //time is a dictionary
    }
}

// Trigger send

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToThird", sender: self)
}
```

and this is the code in the destionation view controller:

```
var hourDictionary : Dictionary = ["String" : "String"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    print(hourDictionary)
    cell.label2.text = hourDictionary["\(indexPath.row)"]

    return cell
}
```

However `hourDictionary` remains with this value:

```
["String": "String"]
["String": "String"]
["String": "String"]
["String": "String"]
["String": "String"]
["String": "String"]
```

Time is being initialized as a dictionary:

```
    var eatingTime : Dictionary = ["String" : "String"]
```

Already tried to replace the func Prepare for segue but still not working:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToThird" {
        let Ps = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
        Ps.hourDictionary = Time
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you init Time

Comment: like this: var Time : Dictionary = ["String" : "String"]

Comment: assured that the prepare method is called ?? also Time contains same content as destination dictionary , how then you expect a difference

Comment: The signature of `prepare(for` is wrong, so it's not getting called. Please see the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: I tried that solution, however i get the same result in ThirdViewController